# Getting the original function from a Taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

According to Taylor Theorem: f(x)= Pn(x) + Rn(x), where Pn(x) is the n-th Taylor polynomial and Rn(x) is the error term.

If I have a function, I know how to derive its Taylor series. But what can I do to get the original function if I have only the Taylor series expansion, and I am given that this series converges to its function? (i.e. Rn(x) goes to zero)

Comment: Without any further assumptions you cannot conclude anything about the original function. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/q/72/295224

Comment: By definition, a Taylor series is a a series of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$. So, there is a function $f$ involved from the start. Or do you have something different in mind when you refer to “Taylor series”?